# Why I receive ImportError: cannot import name 'just_fix_windows_console' from 'colorama'?

Tags: python, colorama

I have to use BayesianOptimization for hyper parameter tuning for neural networks, for the same when I'm importing it using, `from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization`, the following error is obtained

```
`ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_28896\1719632484.py in <module>
----> 1 from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bayes_opt\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .bayesian_optimization import BayesianOptimization, Events
      2 from .domain_reduction import SequentialDomainReductionTransformer
      3 from .util import UtilityFunction
      4 from .logger import ScreenLogger, JSONLogger
      5 from .constraint import ConstraintModel

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bayes_opt\bayesian_optimization.py in <module>
      3 from bayes_opt.constraint import ConstraintModel
      4 
----> 5 from .target_space import TargetSpace
      6 from .event import Events, DEFAULT_EVENTS
      7 from .logger import _get_default_logger

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bayes_opt\target_space.py in <module>
      2 
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from .util import ensure_rng, NotUniqueError
      5 from .util import Colours
      6 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bayes_opt\util.py in <module>
      3 from scipy.stats import norm
      4 from scipy.optimize import minimize
----> 5 from colorama import just_fix_windows_console
      6 
      7 

ImportError: cannot import name 'just_fix_windows_console' from 'colorama' (C:\Users\saiga\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\colorama\__init__.py)
`
```

- I have tried importing 'colorama', and other modules in it, which was working, but this name isn't.
- Also BayesianOptimization can be directly imported, using `import BayesianOptimization` but I need to call BayesianOPtimization in the program later using

```
gbm_bo = BayesianOptimization(gbm_cl_bo, params_gbm, random_state=111)
```

where gbm_cl_bo are functions defined. But then, the below given error is coming.

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

So, inorder to avoid this I think I need to call BayesianOptimization from a parent directory. For the same I have also tried the following code : "from .BayesianOptimization import BayesianOptimization", but received the error as

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_28896\572044167.py in <module>
----> 1 from .BayesianOptimization import BayesianOptimization

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

1. So how to fix the above import error?
2. Otherwise, is there an alternate way of calling BayesianOptimization, so as not to get the error "'module' object is not callable".

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Stack Overflow is not tech support. If simply *importing third-party library code* is causing an error (without needing any of your own code), that is an issue with the library, which should be brought up on the library's bug tracker and/or resolved by reading the library's documentation. If someone else's code expects yet another person's code to provide some functionality, and the functionality isn't provided, then clearly there is a version conflict.

Comment: "So, inorder to avoid this I think I need to call BayesianOptimization from a parent directory" This reflects a fundamentally flawed model of how importing works. If importing A imports B which imports C which fails to import D, then the A import was definitely not the problem; and trying to import A "from" somewhere else cannot possibly solve the problem (either it will fail to find A, as in your case, or it will find A in the same actual location, causing the same problem).

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. The first step to solving a problem like this is to [try putting the relevant part of the error message into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cannot+import+name+%27just_fix_windows_console%27+from+%27colorama%27). When I try this, one of the top results is [the PyPI page for colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/), and looking in the page for `just_fix_windows_console` directly tells us that it was added in 0.4.6, i.e. the latest version.

Comment: This should be reported as a bug against `bayes_opt`; because you were able to install it successfully, it shows that the packaging setup for `bayes_opt` is not requesting the version of `colorama` that it needs.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [Done.](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization/pull/389)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the changelog for colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst), that function was added in the latest version of the library, 0.4.6.

Make sure you have that version installed, with e.g. `pip install -U colorama`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using poetry as a package manager, I tried

```
poetry add colorama==0.4.4
```

Which also downgraded bayesian-optimisation

- Updating colorama (0.4.6 -> 0.4.4)
- Updating bayesian-optimization (1.4.2 -> 1.4.1)

I made some progress to a new unrelated error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The colorama package requires a python version above 3.6. Otherwise colorama=0.4.5 is installed and, leading to a failure of a sucessful run. Therefore during creating the environment install a newer python version